# Creating unity materials at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a custom text language like YAML with simple syntax that looks like this.

```
object : Health : NUMBER : 1.0f (this's a comment)
object : WeaponColor : U_MATERIAL : Diffuse : TEX_BRICK : 55 : 55 : 55 : 255 (creates a new instance of a unity material with the specified parameters)
```

The previous example creates an object with an array of values with **1 float and 1 unity material** **where the value of the number is 1.0 and the material uses the Legacy Diffuse shader with a texture named TEX_BRICK and an rgb color with the values 55 55 55 255.**

The problem is how can I create a new material at runtime? do I write something like this...

```
var mat = new Material("shader name", color, etc, ...)
```

or materials can't be created at runtime?

I use C# and unity 2018.1.0b5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-ctor.html).

You can create a Material specifying the shader first. That would be Legacy Diffuse. Then use:

```
material.SetTexture("_MainTex", thetexture)
```

And:

```
material.SetColor(r, g, b, a);
```

to set the main texture and color.